# Create new variable based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to know whether an change of values for column `type` **after second row** and **number of changes** in column `type` after second row. For example in id ==1, type==1e,1e,2d,2h. then when we look after second row type changes from 1e to 2d then 2h. Therefore there is a change and the number of change is 2.

```
data<- data.frame(id= c(1, 1, 1, 1,  2, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2, 3, 3, 3,3 ,3,3,4,4,4, 5,5), 
                   type=c("1e","1e","2d","2h","1c","1c","1e","2d","2h","2j","1e",
                          "1e","2e","1e","1e","2h","1c","1c","1c", "1j","1j"))
```

Desired Output:

```
 id type change_of_type_after_2nd_row count 
   1    1e   NA     2
   1    1e   NA     2 
   1    2d   yes    2
   1    2h   yes    2
   2    1c   NA     4 
   2    1c   NA     4
   2    1e   yes    4
   2    2d   yes    4
   2    2h   yes    4
   2    2j   yes    4
   3    1e   NA     3
   3    1e   NA     3
   3    2e   yes    3
   3    1e   yes    3
   3    1e   No     3
   3    2h   yes    3
   4    1c   NA     0
   4    1c   NA     0
   4    1c   No     0
   5    1j   NA     0
   5    1j   NA     0
```

Please help?

Comment: if any change after 2nd row in column `type`  with in a group id = yes, else =No. for example for id=1, 2nd row==1e, 3rd==2d, 4throw==2h. So there is a change from 1e to 2d (yes) and also, from 2d to 2h (yes). However id ==4, 2nd row=1c and 3rd row =1c, then no change in `type`  so change==`No` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouped by 'id', create a 'new' column with the run-length-id (`rleid`) of 'type' and a sequence column ('rn'), then get the 'count' by taking the number of distinct elements of 'new' less than 1 ('count') and 'change_of_type..' with a condition created with `case_when` based on the row number and `duplicated` values in 'new'

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
out <- data %>%
     group_by(id) %>% 
     mutate(new = rleid(type), rn = row_number(), 
        count = n_distinct(new)-1,
      change_of_type_after_2nd_row = case_when(rn >2 & 
          duplicated(new) ~ 'No', rn > 2 ~ 'Yes')) %>%
     ungroup %>% 
     select(-new)
```

-output

```
as.data.frame(out)
  id type rn count change_of_type_after_2nd_row
1   1   1e  1     2                         <NA>
2   1   1e  2     2                         <NA>
3   1   2d  3     2                          Yes
4   1   2h  4     2                          Yes
5   2   1c  1     4                         <NA>
6   2   1c  2     4                         <NA>
7   2   1e  3     4                          Yes
8   2   2d  4     4                          Yes
9   2   2h  5     4                          Yes
10  2   2j  6     4                          Yes
11  3   1e  1     3                         <NA>
12  3   1e  2     3                         <NA>
13  3   2e  3     3                          Yes
14  3   1e  4     3                          Yes
15  3   1e  5     3                           No
16  3   2h  6     3                          Yes
17  4   1c  1     0                         <NA>
18  4   1c  2     0                         <NA>
19  4   1c  3     0                           No
20  5   1j  1     0                         <NA>
21  5   1j  2     0                         <NA>
```